# div vertical align not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

After searching through [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649106/div-vertical-align-middle-css/24366868#24366868) [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102054/div-vertical-align-not-working), I can't get `vertical-align: middle` working inside a div.

What the desired result is, both with `float: left` present in the div attributes:

 `________   _______
|        | |       |
| lorem  | | ipsum |
|________| |_______|`

```css
.tile {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
#nav {
  display: table;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile" id="nav">
  <div class="tile middle">lorem</div>
  <div class="tile">ipsum</div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Unless it is impossible as stated in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102054/div-vertical-align-not-working) article.

Comment: Amending `height: 100%;` to `.middle` does not resolve the issue, unless you're saying it's impossible?

Comment: Remove the float from the `tile` class or remove the `tile` class from your inner divs.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3a6a5b77/1/

Comment: @MarkLeiber  Thank you! I can work with that. Are you able to offer an explanation as to why?

Comment: The float conflicts with the table display (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819931/center-image-vertically-and-horizontally-inside-of-div-with-floatleft). Also note that adding a line-height of 50px to the tile class also resolves your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have inner div the same class as parent, remove it, it will work

```
   <div class="nav">
   <div class="tile middle">lorem</div>
   <div class="tile">ipsum</div>
   </div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/murjjchg/

Answer (score 0):

May be, this work for you.

**CSS:**

```
#nav { 
    display: table; 
     width:50%;
}
.title { 
    float: left;  
    width: 100%; 
    display:table-cell;  
    background-color: blue; 
}
.middle {  
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red; 
}
.cincuenta {           
    text-align: center;
     min-height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="cincuenta middle">lorem</div>
    <div class="cincuenta title">ipsum</div>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3a6a5b77/3/)**</kbd>